# How can I store the data in memory and use by the other Button click event to display the data?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, global-variables

Here is the code, but the datatable is NULL in ButtonExport click event, how can i pass the DataTable to Sub ButtonExport_Click ? I dont want to store in Session as the data is too big

***Here is the class clsGlobalVarriable***

```
Public Class clsGlobalVariable

    Private _gdt As DataTable

    Public Property globalDataTable As DataTable
        Get
            Return _gdt
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DataTable)
            _gdt = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

***Here is the From frmTest code:***

```
Public Class frmTest
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private gdt As New clsGlobalVariable

    Protected Sub ButtonInactivePC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonInactivePC.Click

        Try
            Dim func As New clsFunction
            Dim command As String = "Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -NotLike '*Windows Server*'} -Property * | select Name, CanonicalName, operatingSystem, LastLogonDate, Description, whenChanged | Where {($_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)) -and ($_.LastLogonDate -ne $NULL)}"

            Dim arr As New ArrayList
            arr.Add("Name")
            arr.Add("CanonicalName")
            arr.Add("operatingSystem")
            arr.Add("LastLogonDate")
            arr.Add("whenChanged")
            arr.Add("Description")

            gdt.globalDataTable = func.PSObjectToDataTable(command, arr)
            Me.GridView1.DataSource = gdt.globalDataTable
            Me.GridView1.DataBind()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.LabelDebug.Text = "Button Click" + ex.Message
        End Try


    End Sub

    Protected Sub ButtonExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonExport.Click

        Dim func As New clsFunction
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt = (DirectCast(Me.GridView1.DataSource, DataTable))
        Me.LabelDebug.Text = "Global Data Table Count = " & dt.Rows.Count

    End Sub
```

Comment: but if you do not click ButtonInactivePC button, you donot have any data in datagrid, so data are of course null, or am I missing something?

Comment: I want the user click the ButtonInactivePC, the function will store the data into a Global Variable (i store in a property of a class call clsGlobalVariable). I declare the clsGlobalVariable in Form (not in any function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use alternative for the Excel Export, i am not going to pass the DataTable, instead i pass the GridView to the Export to Excel function

***Add the following sub right after Page_load, this is to avoid the GridView error***

```
Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)
End Sub
```

***Here is the Code:***

```
Public Sub ExportFromGridview(ByVal gv As GridView, ByVal response As HttpResponse

    response.Clear()
    response.Write("<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html;charset=utf-8>")
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" & Now & ".xls")
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"
    Dim stringWrite As System.IO.StringWriter = New System.IO.StringWriter()
    Dim htmlWrite As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter = New HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite)
    gv.RenderControl(htmlWrite)

    response.Write(stringWrite.ToString())
    response.End()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with webpages that show data to the user, and the user takes some action on that data you either need to store the data somewhere in their computer, your computer (the server) or rely on the fact that it's still stored in the computer you got it from. As a process you have undertaken:

- You generate a grid from querying AD
- You send the grid to the customer's computer - so it's stored there as a visual representation (and maybe also ViewState)
- It's still stored in AD, where you got it
- You could also store it locally on the server somehow - Session, DB, text file, whatever

Decide on which of these to use when the user clicks Export:

- Dig it out of the viewstate or other data that was sent to the user - for this you'll have to code things up so it comes back from the user
- Get it out of AD again - simple to do; you did it once and sent it to the user in HTML. Getting it again and sending it to the user again this time as a CSV isn't really any different from the first time you did it
- Restore it from wherever you kept it on the server

Choose the first if your user is going to modify the data or choose to export only some of it - the data he sends back to you should indicate which bits he wants exporting.

Choose the second option if you want an easy life, and it's just a straight export, no editing or subset of data. Write one method that gets the data out of AD and then use it in either place, one to form HTML/fill a grid, in the other to send a file to the user. Don't get hung up on "well I already got this data once, it's a waste to get it again" - no-one writes a Login Page and thinks "i'll only ever look up a user from the DB once, then get the server to remember the login data forever more and use it next time there is a login request" - they store the data in the db, and look it up every time there is a login. DBs store data and perform the same queries over and over again. This is no different

You probably wouldn't choose the third option, for reasons already mentioned

Comment: There is no Global Variable concept in the code within the same Form / Class?

Comment: It's not about that; it's about being across requests. This is a web app; your user clicks a Inactive button, he sees a grid of html sent by the server, the server forgets about everything, the user clicks an Export button, the server finds nothing in the grid. You didn't establish any mechanism for the server tor emember anything between the two HTTP requests